# Upload list of files to GCS without for loop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have to filter the GCS using some search criteria and capture the filtered files in a python list(number of files will vary every time). I want to move them to separate GCS folder in same bucket. Currently I am looping through the list and calling **gsutil cp** for every file. As my list is dynamic, is there any way to implement this without loop because sometimes my list will have more than million files.

Comment: I'm thinking that gsutil is a command line command.  I don't think you will be able to supply a million parameters (one for each file) to any command line command.  Instead, consider write code that will use the underlying GCS API to move each file and call that API once for each file.   I am assuming that simple wildcard won't work for you ... otherwise it would be simple as described here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames

Comment: @Kolban, Thanks for the suggestion but I see for my usecase, I have list and i need to upload them using loop. I wanted to get rid of loop. It would be helpful if you any example is provided

Comment: I don't think you are going to get rid of the loop.  What is it you want to achieve?  If it is a parallel upload ... think of your question ... if you have a million files, you can't form a million concurrent connections to GCS.  I think we both agree that we can loop over the files one at a time and send each one serially.  Given that idea, can you clarify what it is about that notion that you would like to change and why?